# After certain load of GEOADD & BRPOP, Redis/Docker responds with errors

Tags: docker, go, redis, go-redis

I am using [go-redis](https://github.com/go-redis/redis) to connect to Redis server running on docker desktop while running my go app straight on my mac.

This my client setup:

```golang
package redis

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"

    "github.com/go-redis/redis/v8"
)

var redisClient *RedisClient

type RedisClient struct {
    *redis.Client
}

func GetRedisClient() *RedisClient {
    if redisClient != nil {
        return redisClient
    }
    host := os.Getenv("REDIS_HOST")
    port := os.Getenv("REDIS_PORT")
    password := os.Getenv("REDIS_PASS")

    client := redis.NewClient(&redis.Options{
        Addr:     fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s", host, port),
        Password: password, // no password set
        DB:       0,
    })

    redisClient = &RedisClient{
        Client: client,
    }

    return redisClient

}
```

Docker:

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:

    redis:
        container_name: redis
        image: redis:6.2
        ports:
            - "6379:6379"
        ulimits:
          nofile:
            soft: 65536
            hard: 65536
```

The app will expose websocket connections to drivers that will communicate their current location every second and then save them in Redis using `GEOADD`.
Also the app will expose another set of websocket connections to the same drivers for general notifications if any using `BRPOP`.
After 70 driver of websocket connections I get errors from the extra drivers trying to connect. The errors come from the function that saves the location to Redis. The errors I get:
`dial tcp [::1]:6379: socket: too many open files`
and sometimes `dial tcp: lookup localhost: no such host`

```golang
func (r *RedisClient) SetPoint(ctx context.Context, item *Identifier, loc *Location) error {
    geoLocaiton := &redis.GeoLocation{Name: item.Id, Latitude: loc.Lat, Longitude: loc.Lng}
    if err := r.GeoAdd(ctx, item.key(), geoLocaiton).Err(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error adding geo", err)
        return errors.New("failed to set point")
    }
    return nil
}
```

For general notifications (timeout on the pulling is zero) meaning infinate:

```golang
type DriverData struct {
    Status   OrderStatusType `json:"status,omitempty"`
    DriverId uint            `json:"driver_id,omitempty"`
    UserId   uint            `json:"user_id,omitempty"`
}

func (config *Config) DriverOrderStatus(c *gin.Context) {
    driverID := utils.ToUint(auth.GetToken(c).Subject)
    ctx := c.Request.Context()

    // order := models.GetOrder(config.Db)
    // var _ = order.GetActiveOrderForUser(driverID)

    wsconn, err := websocket.Accept(c.Writer, c.Request, &websocket.AcceptOptions{InsecureSkipVerify: true})
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    // if order.ID != 0 {
    //  var _ = wsjson.Write(ctx, wsconn, &UserData{Order: order, Status: order.Status, Driver: order.Driver})
    // } else {
    //  var _ = wsjson.Write(ctx, wsconn, &UserData{ResetOrder: true})
    // }

    defer wsconn.Close(websocket.StatusInternalError, "")

    closeRead := wsconn.CloseRead(ctx)

    driverDataCh := make(chan *DriverData, 1000)

    go func() {
    loop:
        for {
            select {
            case <-closeRead.Done():
                break loop
            default:
                if status, err := config.Redis.DriverPullStatus(ctx, driverID); err == nil {
                    driverDataCh <- &DriverData{Status: status.Status, DriverId: status.DriverID, UserId: status.UserID}
                }
            }
        }
        fmt.Println("redis pulling data is over")
    }()

loop:
    for {
        select {
        case <-closeRead.Done():
            break loop
        case driverData := <-driverDataCh:
            if err := wsjson.Write(ctx, wsconn, driverData); err != nil {
                break loop
            }
        }
    }

    fmt.Println("sending updates to user is over")

}
```

This is Redis server info:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> info
# Server
redis_version:6.2.6
redis_git_sha1:00000000
redis_git_dirty:0
redis_build_id:a0adc3471b8cfa72
redis_mode:standalone
os:Linux 5.10.47-linuxkit x86_64
arch_bits:64
multiplexing_api:epoll
atomicvar_api:atomic-builtin
gcc_version:10.3.1
process_id:1
process_supervised:no
run_id:d92005e2ccb89ea8e3be57e3bb1b79e0e323c2a7
tcp_port:6379
server_time_usec:1654937072463352
uptime_in_seconds:325287
uptime_in_days:3
hz:10
configured_hz:10
lru_clock:10769904
executable:/data/redis-server
config_file:
io_threads_active:0

# Clients
connected_clients:104
cluster_connections:0
maxclients:10000
client_recent_max_input_buffer:48
client_recent_max_output_buffer:0
blocked_clients:81
tracking_clients:0
clients_in_timeout_table:0

# Memory
used_memory:3081168
used_memory_human:2.94M
used_memory_rss:5791744
used_memory_rss_human:5.52M
used_memory_peak:5895528
used_memory_peak_human:5.62M
used_memory_peak_perc:52.26%
used_memory_overhead:2944804
used_memory_startup:809880
used_memory_dataset:136364
used_memory_dataset_perc:6.00%
allocator_allocated:3166992
allocator_active:3862528
allocator_resident:6742016
total_system_memory:4125036544
total_system_memory_human:3.84G
used_memory_lua:37888
used_memory_lua_human:37.00K
used_memory_scripts:0
used_memory_scripts_human:0B
number_of_cached_scripts:0
maxmemory:0
maxmemory_human:0B
maxmemory_policy:noeviction
allocator_frag_ratio:1.22
allocator_frag_bytes:695536
allocator_rss_ratio:1.75
allocator_rss_bytes:2879488
rss_overhead_ratio:0.86
rss_overhead_bytes:-950272
mem_fragmentation_ratio:1.88
mem_fragmentation_bytes:2712392
mem_not_counted_for_evict:0
mem_replication_backlog:0
mem_clients_slaves:0
mem_clients_normal:2134588
mem_aof_buffer:0
mem_allocator:jemalloc-5.1.0
active_defrag_running:0
lazyfree_pending_objects:0
lazyfreed_objects:0

# Persistence
loading:0
current_cow_size:0
current_cow_size_age:0
current_fork_perc:0.00
current_save_keys_processed:0
current_save_keys_total:0
rdb_changes_since_last_save:3636
rdb_bgsave_in_progress:0
rdb_last_save_time:1654936992
rdb_last_bgsave_status:ok
rdb_last_bgsave_time_sec:1
rdb_current_bgsave_time_sec:-1
rdb_last_cow_size:450560
aof_enabled:0
aof_rewrite_in_progress:0
aof_rewrite_scheduled:0
aof_last_rewrite_time_sec:-1
aof_current_rewrite_time_sec:-1
aof_last_bgrewrite_status:ok
aof_last_write_status:ok
aof_last_cow_size:0
module_fork_in_progress:0
module_fork_last_cow_size:0

# Stats
total_connections_received:1271
total_commands_processed:296750
instantaneous_ops_per_sec:45
total_net_input_bytes:27751095
total_net_output_bytes:1254190
instantaneous_input_kbps:4.16
instantaneous_output_kbps:12.46
rejected_connections:0
sync_full:0
sync_partial_ok:0
sync_partial_err:0
expired_keys:0
expired_stale_perc:0.00
expired_time_cap_reached_count:0
expire_cycle_cpu_milliseconds:18136
evicted_keys:0
keyspace_hits:10
keyspace_misses:3567
pubsub_channels:0
pubsub_patterns:0
latest_fork_usec:6453
total_forks:41
migrate_cached_sockets:0
slave_expires_tracked_keys:0
active_defrag_hits:0
active_defrag_misses:0
active_defrag_key_hits:0
active_defrag_key_misses:0
tracking_total_keys:0
tracking_total_items:0
tracking_total_prefixes:0
unexpected_error_replies:0
total_error_replies:6
dump_payload_sanitizations:0
total_reads_processed:297924
total_writes_processed:295658
io_threaded_reads_processed:0
io_threaded_writes_processed:0

# Replication
role:master
connected_slaves:0
master_failover_state:no-failover
master_replid:fc426cf72670e6ad09221bcb9c3423a1e1fab47e
master_replid2:0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
master_repl_offset:0
second_repl_offset:-1
repl_backlog_active:0
repl_backlog_size:1048576
repl_backlog_first_byte_offset:0
repl_backlog_histlen:0

# CPU
used_cpu_sys:428.939381
used_cpu_user:123.850311
used_cpu_sys_children:0.755309
used_cpu_user_children:0.065924
used_cpu_sys_main_thread:428.485425
used_cpu_user_main_thread:123.679341

# Modules

# Errorstats
errorstat_ERR:count=6

# Cluster
cluster_enabled:0

# Keyspace
db0:keys=6,expires=0,avg_ttl=0
```

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of searching, it turns out that is caused by the max "open file descriptor". Every websocket connection will open a file descriptor. Every machine has a limit. In linux/unix, this is defined under ulimit.

More into that in this [article](https://centrifugal.github.io/centrifugo/blog/scaling_websocket/).
In order to update ulimit in mac, refer to this [post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/32235/how-to-properly-increase-a-ulimit-n-limits).